# Match a specific item in a collection using MongoDB aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In the following document, I'd like to find the table object which has the column matching the criteria

> (label is 'abc' or (name is 'abc' and label is empty))

```
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "table1",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "abc",
          "label": "xyz"
        },
        {
          "name": "def",
          "label": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "table2",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "xxx",
          "label": "yyy"
        },
        {
          "name": "zzz",
          "label": "abc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The expected answer is table2 object.

The following query returns both table1 and table2. I think the 'match' clause is applied to the entire column array not column by column. I'd like to get the table object as the final result So unwinding at column level is not an option.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
            {$unwind : "$tables"},
            {"$match":
                {"$or": 
                    [
                        {"tables.columns.label": "abc"},
                        {"tables.columns.name":"abc", "tables.columns.label": ""}
                    ]
                }
            }
)
```

How do I match column by column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator:

```js
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
    {
        $unwind: "$tables"
    },
    {
        $match:
        {
            "$or":
            [
                {
                    "tables.columns.label": "abc"
                },
                {
                    "tables.columns":
                    {
                        $elemMatch:
                        {
                            "name": "abc",
                            "label": ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
)
```